# Tcl lindex and expr: non-numeric failure

Tags: tcl, expr

If I put only below it works.

```
"\{[lindex ($columns) 1] - 30.3]"
```

If I put as below, it doesnt work. Wonder why?

```
"\{[lindex ($columns) 1] - 30.3] [expr [lindex ($columns) 2] -30.3] \}"
```

My script as below:

```
foreach line $lines {
    set columns [split $line " "]
    puts "\{[lindex ($columns) 1] - 30.3] [expr [lindex ($columns) 2] -30.3] \}"
}
```

Comment: The first version is… only really working by chance. It has non-matching square brackets, but in the way that isn't a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're writing `($columns)` instead of `$columns`, which is concatenating parentheses on the list you're passing to `lindex`. In this case, I suspect that the list has three simple elements (e.g., `1 2 3`) and the result of the concatenation is `(1 2 3)`. The middle element at index 1 is still fine, but the element at the end (index 2) is now `3)` and that's non-numeric.

The whole thing is a syntax error. Here's how to write it correctly:

```
puts "\{[expr {[lindex $columns 1] - 30.3}] [expr {[lindex $columns 2] -30.3}] \}"
```

However, in this case it might instead be a bit clearer to write this:

```
lassign [split $line " "] c1 c2 c3
puts [format "{%f %f}" [expr {$c2 - 30.3}] [expr {$c3 - 30.3}]]
```

Comment: %.4f - seems to round up the final number. What would be the syntax, if I do not want the final number to be round up to 3 digit (ie: 12.1230)

Comment: You could use `%s` to get no rounding at all (assuming recent-enough Tcl). Otherwise there's lots of options for formatting a number. Worth asking that as a separate question where you lay out exactly what you want to get out of it…